# Intuition behind why rotating a point $180^\circ$ about the origin give the same result as reflecting it with respect to the origin

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, intuition

I understand that the outcomes of those two actions could be proven mathematically, and we can see that those results match. I also understand that I can visualize those actions and see how the resultant points will end up on the same spot. However, I don't understand how those 2 actions are *related* as they both give rise to the same phenomenon.

Comment: What you've mentioned is a special case. You're rotating the point by $180°$ along the line joining that point and origin in the direction of origin. There are many other possibilities to rotate the point by $180°$ along any other line where the new point will not be reflection of original point w.r.t. origin.

Comment: Do not look only at one point!  Would you say you don't understand how $x^2 + 1$ and $3x - 1$ can be equal at $x = 1$ when the functions are not the same?  That they are equal at *one number* does not make them equal at *all numbers*, and indeed $x^2 + 1$ and $3x-1$ agree only at $x = 1$. Everywhere else they are different. Similarly, if you rotate by 180 degrees around the origin and reflect across a line $L$ through the origin then *most* points are not sent to the same place under both transformations!

Comment: Only the points on the line $L'$ through the origin that is perpendicular to $L$ are sent to the same place under 180 degree rotation around the origin and reflection across $L$. All other points are sent to different places.  The upshot is that when you want to compare two functions on the plane, you should look at them *everywhere* and not focus on a very small set of points to think you "understand" the functions just by checking them there. For some functions on the plane, behavior at a few (well-chosen) points determine them everywhere, but you need to be careful about where you check.

Comment: I'm not sure why SarGe and KCd are referring to reflection about lines; this is clearly a question about reflection in the origin. That said, this is a tricky question to answer without more details. Is there an intuitive way that you understand reflections/rotations that you can't seem to connect?

Comment: @SarGe Thanks for pointing that out! I was indeed referring to the specific case of rotating about the origin.

Comment: @KCd Hi, I apologize for my inaccuracy - as I commented above, I was referring to rotating about the origin. However, I'm pretty sure this specific circumstance, a point that goes through those 2 actions separately will always have the same resultant coordinate?

Comment: @user804886 I don't quite have a very accurate way of visualizing them yet. What I have done is merely picturing how those 2 actions are performed to a point and can feel that they would roughly give the same result.

Comment: One way to think about it to say that to rotate a point, you first move it to the origin along a line, then you move it away from the origin the same distance, but at a different angle. We know that a 180 degree angle is just a straight line, so in that specific case, move the point along a straight line to the origin, and then just keep moving it in the same direction past the origin, until it is the same distance from the origin that it started. But this is the same thing as a reflection. I think that this gives a visual intuition why they're the same thing (if you can follow it, that is)

Comment: Your assumption that the two operations are identical is true only in the plane perpendicular to the rotation axis. Consider the 3D space, in particular the plane $z=0$. In this plane choose $P_1(1,0,0)$ and $P_2(1,1,0)$. If you rotate around $z$ axis $P_1'=(-1,0,0)$ and $P_2'=(-1,-1,0)$, identical to the reflection through $(0,0,0)$. But a rotation around $y$ axis will give $P_1''(-1,0,0)$ and $P_2''=(-1,1,0)$, which is not the same (the $y$ component does not change)

Comment: This is not a phenomenon. This are two different operation where the outcome is true for a certain case. It is similar to the case that $2^2$, $2X2$ gives the same result as $2+2$